# Error ReactJs : Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I got this error but I did not use any useEffect . I just wrote a function to update the input value and when I click on the button to search the input value, this error occurs. Do you have any solution?

```
import "./SearchInput.css";
import Search from "../../../assets/Images/icon/search-normal.svg";
import { Navigate } from "react-router";
import { React, useRef, useState, createContext } from "react";
import { useAppContext } from "../../../Context/SearchContext/SearchContext";

const SearchInput = (props) => {
  const [inputChange, setInputChanage] = useState("");
  const [fireNavigate, setFireNavigate] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const { setSearchValue } = useAppContext();

  const inputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setInputChanage(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      setFireNavigate(true);
      setSearchValue(inputRef.current.value);
      console.log(inputRef.current.value);
    }
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setFireNavigate(true);
    setSearchValue(inputRef.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="search-input-container">
      <input
        className="search-input"
        ref={inputRef}
        onChange={inputChangeHandler}
        value={inputChange}
        type="text"
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      />
      <button className="search-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
        <img src={Search} width="100%" height="100%" alt="search icon" />
      </button>
      {fireNavigate ? <Navigate to="/search" /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchInput;
```

Comment: `{fireNavigate ? <Navigate to='/search' /> : null}` You're redirecting to /search, but will this `SearchInput` component still be on the page when you get there?

Comment: @NicholasTower   Yes, It will be there and every things work but when I change the input value and click enter, I got an endless error .

Answer (score 0):

When you set `fireNavigate` to true, you now render a `<Navigate to='/search'/>` element. The purpose of this element is to do a `useEffect` which redirects to the /search page. But once the browser gets there, SearchInput renders again and fireNavigate is still true. So you render the `Navigate` element again, which redirects again, and the loop repeats.

If you're using version 6 of react-router, i recommend deleting the fireNavigate state and the `<Navigate>` element, and using the useNavigate hook instead:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

const SearchInput = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // ...

  const handleClick = () => {
    setSearchValue(inputRef.current.value);
    navigate('/search'); // <-- do the navigate right now, once.
  };

  return (
    <div className="search-input-container">
      <input
        className="search-input"
        ref={inputRef}
        onChange={inputChangeHandler}
        value={inputChange}
        type="text"
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      />
      <button className="search-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
        <img src={Search} width="100%" height="100%" alt="search icon" />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you're using version 5, then useHistory can do something similar.